# RichTextBox Regex Error

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I am trying to use `Regex` to highlight numbers in my `RichTextBox` RTB, and it works fine, except when I press move the caret position to above where I was, it selects the stuff below, and when I type, it dissapears, unless I am constantly pressing the left key, which is a real nuisance.

Code:

**MyRegex.cs**

```
namespace REGEX_MY
{
    public class REGEX_CLASS
    {
        public static RichTextBox HIGHLIGHT(RichTextBox RTB, int StartPos)
        {
            Regex Red = new Regex("1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0");
            RTB.SelectAll();
            RTB.SelectionColor = Color.White;
            RTB.Select(RTB.Text.Length, 1);

            foreach (Match Match in Red.Matches(RTB.Text))
            {
                RTB.Select(Match.Index, Match.Length);
                RTB.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                RTB.SelectionStart = StartPos;
                RTB.SelectionColor = Color.White;
            }
            return RTB;
        }
    }          
}
```

**MyForm.cs**

```
public void DoIt()
{
    RTB = REGEX_MY.REGEX_CLASS.HIGHLIGHT(RTB, RTB.SelectionStart);
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RTB.Select(Match.Index, Match.Length)` in `foreach` statement is jumping a 1 length selection over the matched digits. When it finishes, it keeps the selection over the last matched digit, and when you press any key the selection does not disappear but the cursor moves forward, so the next character gets overwritten.

The solution is to bring back the cursor to the starting position without selection range just **after** the `foreach` statement gets finished, like this `RTB.Select(StartPos, 0)`

```
foreach (Match Match in Red.Matches(RTB.Text))
{
    RTB.Select(Match.Index, Match.Length);
    RTB.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    RTB.SelectionStart = StartPos;
    RTB.SelectionColor = Color.White;
 }
 RTB.Select(StartPos, 0);
 return RTB;
```

Comment: A quick question - It keeps flashing whenever I do something [type]. Is there any way of stopping that from happening?

Comment: It has reduced the amount of flashing, but still not eradicated it. I am using multiple Regex statements. Can it be solved?

Comment: I guess that's an effect of the control being redrawn when the selection is done in `RTB.Select(Match.Index, Match.Length)`. I don't know if you can prevent the control from being redrawn just while the `foreach` statement is in execution. I should investigate.